# Plants for a duck enclosure - Sydney, Australia

Tags: plant-recommendations

I'm looking for suggestions for plants to put in a duck enclosure that are not going to be eaten or trampled by my ducks.

I will have some small raised hills running down two sides of the enclosure and also want something to put around the sides of their pond (about 2m squared) which could be semi-aquatic.

I would also like it to fit in with the surrounds, so something like reeds or the like that makes it look and feel like a duck home.

Answer (score 3):

why not Phragmites communis? water plants where often ducks make their nests. High 1-2 mt, in group, flowers spike, any clima

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Looks like there is also a native Australian version Phragmites Australis.